# Como contar numeros consecutivos dentro de un array?

Tags: php, algoritmos

Buenas estoy practicando realizando distintos tipos de algoritmos y hay uno en el que no puedo entender la lógica o el porque estoy haciendolo mal.

Obtengo un array de numeros enteros del 1 al 9 por ejemplo

```
$myArray = array(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8);
```

Y en el algoritmo debe devolver cual numero se repite mas veces de manera consecutiva y cuantas veces se repite de manera consecutiva.

En este caso sería el 8 que se repite 3 veces de manera consecutiva.

Para ello realicé lo siguieente:

```
$cont = 1;
$longest = $cont;
$number = $myArray[0];

for($i=0; $i<$myArray.length; $i++) {

    if($myArray[i] == $myArray[i+1]){
    
        $cont++;
        
        $longest = $cont;
        
        $number = $myArray[i];
    
    } else {
        
        $cont = 1;
    
    }
    
    if($cont > $longest){
    
        $longest = $cont;
        $number = $myArray[i];
    }

}

echo("Longest: " + $longest + "\n" + "Number: " + $number);
```

Pero por alguna razón esta mal.

El código lo escribí en php, pero al ser una cuestión de lógica no importa el lenguaje en si.

Comment: Has realizado 3 veces la misma pregunta casi en el mismo momento, de distinta forma pero con el mismo objetivo.  ¿Porque no esperas a que te contesten en una antes de volverlo a preguntar?  o bien ¿porque no borras las que ya no necesitas respuesta si es que has avanzado en su resolución? ¿O porque no editas la pregunta si ha sufrido variaciones?  Vas a llenar SOes de preguntas casi iguales y nos vas a volver locos intentando ayudarte cuando quizás ya has avanzado y ya no te hacen falta algunas preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Una estrategia para obtener el número que más se repite y el número de veces que se repite es guardar el valor que tiene el arreglo en una variable, por ejemplo `$old`, y ese valor se va a comparar en la siguiente iteración con el valor que tiene el arreglo en ese ciclo

Si el valor de la iteración actual es igual al valor de la iteración anterior (Que estamos guardando en `$old`) entonces aumentamos un contador (`$count`) que revisa el número de repeticiones del valor actual.

El contador lo podemos inicializar en `1` ya que cada número por lo menos se repite una vez

El valor inicial del número que más se repite (Estoy llamando la variable `$number`) y del valor de la iteración anterior (Estoy llamando la variable `$old`) se inicializan en `null` porque no si inicializas las variables con cualquier valor numérico, por ejemplo 0, podría ser que en el arreglo ese valor también exista y entonces el conteo estaría mal.

En otra variable (`$repetitions`) guardamos el valor más grande de repeticiones seguidas, cuando `$count` sea mayor a `$repetitions` entonces guardamos el valor de `$count` en `$repetitions` y el valor numérico de la iteración actual en el número que más se repite

Cuando el valor de la iteración actual es diferente al valor de la iteración previa entonces regreso el contador `$count` a 1

El ejemplo del código funcionando:

```
<?php
$myArray = array(1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5);
$count = 1;
$repetitions = 0;
$number = null;
$old = null;

foreach ($myArray as $element){
    if ($old == $element) {
        $count++;
        if ($count > $repetitions) {
            $repetitions = $count;
            $number = $element;
        }
    }
    else {
        $count = 1;
    }
    
    $old = $element;
}
echo 'El número que más se repite es: '.$number. ' y se repite '. $repetitions . ' veces.';
?>
```

Resultado del código anterior:

```
El número que más se repite es: 8 y se repite 11 veces.
```